# Inspec command not printing the memory of a server

Tags: ruby, testing, awk, chef-infra, inspec

By executing from inspec.backend.run_command. It's only printing CPU and not memory if i use awk in $memory.

Here is my code:

```
control 'nodes_certs' do  
 impact 0.7               
 title 'nodes_certs'     
 desc 'An optional description...'

nodecert=inspec.backend.run_command("name() { local cpu=$(nproc); local mem=$`(free -g | awk \'/Mem/ {print $2}\')`; echo $cpu; echo $mem ; }; name\'").stdout

print nodecert

end
```

Here is output:

```
16

Profile: tests from mem.rb (tests from mem.rb)
Version: (not specified)
Target:  local://

     No tests executed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your bash script. You don't need backquotes, if you use `$()`. Try changing:

```
$`(free -g | awk \'/Mem/ {print $2}\')`
```

to

```
$(free -g | awk \'/Mem/ {print $2}\')
```